# Sort dataframe by vector r

Tags: r

im having some trouble figuring out how to do this.

I want to sort a dataframe by a column containing factors that are the same as the factors I have in a list.  It is important that the code doesn't change the order of the rows in each factor though.

Ideas?

edit:

```
salmon <- c("red", 3,7, 5)
bass <- c("red", 1,3,5)
shrimp <- c("blue", 1, 4, 2)
carp <- c("orange", 6, 6, 6)

dfex <- data.frame(salmon, bass, shrimp, carp)
dfex <- data.frame(t(dfex))

ordering <- c("blue", "orange", "red")
```

so the idea here is to reorder the dataframe by using the ordering vector

Comment: [Reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, I did down-vote. You were asked for exactly the same in your previous question - to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: dont downvote unless you are going to come back and get rid of downvote when I fix the problem.............

Comment: Usually you just get down vote and you're scr...

Comment: @user2795569, you might want to ping the person you're responding to if you want to get their attention. They may not be watching your question to see whether you've bothered to make an edit or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A combination of `match()` and `order()` should do it.

```
dfex[order(match(dfex[[1]], ordering)), ]
```

`match()` will tell you the index position of each value in the first column as found in `ordering`. And sorting by these positions will result in an order that matches the order of `ordering`.

Answer (score 6):

First, the way you build your data frame is a bit complicated. You can do something like the following instead :

```
dfex <- data.frame(v1=c("salmon","shrimp","carp"),
                   v2=c("red","blue","orange"),
                   v3=c(3,1,6),
                   v4=c(7,4,6),
                   v5=c(5,2,6))
```

Then you can order your data frame by using row names :

```
order <- c("blue", "orange", "red")
rownames(dfex) <- dfex$v2
dfex[order,]
```

Which gives :

```
           v1     v2 v3 v4 v5
blue   shrimp   blue  1  4  2
orange   carp orange  6  6  6
red    salmon    red  3  7  5
```

Comment: Does this work if we have multiples of factor, as in my edited example?  I cant get it to work on my end.

Comment: @juba I'm not sure how you can make this work if you add the `bass` to the data.frame (that creates duplicate rowname using your method).

Comment: @juba i would suggest making a factor out of v2 with the order desired as levels (`dfex$v2<-factor(dfex$v2,levels=order)`) and then order using `dfex[order(dfex$v2),]`.

Comment: @plannapus is right, it won't work if you don't have unique values in your ordering column.